# Visual Basic Best Implementation of Creating an Array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, performance

So I fiddled (please don't shoot me) around with seeing what was the faster implementation for arrays after browsing through MSDN's docs.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h63fsef3.aspx This states that:

> Use the { } syntax when you declare and initialize arrays of basic data types. >For example, use the following syntax:
>
> ```
>    Dim letters5() As String = {"a", "b", "c"}
> ```
>
> Do not use the following syntax:
>
> ```
>    Dim letters6(2) As String
>    letters6(0) = "a"
>    letters6(1) = "b"
>    letters6(2) = "c"`
> ```

I understand that the article was written in the context of coding conventions, and not necessarily geared toward coding for speed/efficiency, but assuming I tested correctly in my dotnetfiddle, the latter syntax that Microsoft prompts you to not use is faster, correct?

https://dotnetfiddle.net/fqK5aQ

Comment: How does the generated CIL (MSIL) compare between the two examples?

Comment: Sorry, you just went well over my head. I wouldn't have an idea how to access it, and Google honestly hasn't been too helpful for me over the last hour.

Comment: As Dai suspected, if add both your snippets to a method , compile it and use Redgate Reflector to recreate the source code, I get `Dim letters5 As String() = New String() {"a", "b", "c"}` and `Dim letters6 As String() = New String() {"a", "b", "c"}`. In other words, both snippets are producing identical executable code.

Comment: You should be able to view the CIL from within your dotnetfiddle, no? Click on the "View IL" button.

Comment: Aha, found it. Interesting. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting.  Looking at the generated IL in LINQPad (not sure how this compares to a normal compile - I assume it's the same, but could be wrong), the IL for the two ways to initialize the array is slightly different.

```
Dim letters5() As String = {"a", "b", "c"}
```

```
IL_0000:  ldc.i4.3    
IL_0001:  newarr      System.String
IL_0006:  stloc.1     // VB$LW$t_array$S0
IL_0007:  ldloc.1     // VB$LW$t_array$S0
IL_0008:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0009:  ldstr       "a"
IL_000E:  stelem.ref  
IL_000F:  ldloc.1     // VB$LW$t_array$S0
IL_0010:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0011:  ldstr       "b"
IL_0016:  stelem.ref  
IL_0017:  ldloc.1     // VB$LW$t_array$S0
IL_0018:  ldc.i4.2    
IL_0019:  ldstr       "c"
IL_001E:  stelem.ref  
IL_001F:  ldloc.1     // VB$LW$t_array$S0
IL_0020:  stloc.0     // letters5
IL_0021:  ret
```

vs.

```
Dim letters6(2) As String
letters6(0) = "a"
letters6(1) = "b"
letters6(2) = "c"
```

```
IL_0000:  ldc.i4.3    
IL_0001:  newarr      System.String
IL_0006:  stloc.0     // letters6
IL_0007:  ldloc.0     // letters6
IL_0008:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0009:  ldstr       "a"
IL_000E:  stelem.ref  
IL_000F:  ldloc.0     // letters6
IL_0010:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0011:  ldstr       "b"
IL_0016:  stelem.ref  
IL_0017:  ldloc.0     // letters6
IL_0018:  ldc.i4.2    
IL_0019:  ldstr       "c"
IL_001E:  stelem.ref  
IL_001F:  ret
```

The first version seems to create a temporary variable for the array and copy the reference to the actual variable, which takes two extra instructions.  So, it does seem less efficient, but I suppose the nicer code is a worthwhile tradeoff in normal usage.

Comment: I'm curious if C#'s compiler generates the same output using its equivalent syntax.

Comment: @Dai It does seem to, although I had to disable optimizations in LINQPad, otherwise the single line version was optimized away, and this added an extra `nop` at the beginning! :-)

Comment: Eh, personal preference, but I think the second version looks nicer. At least, to the untrained eye. 

Regardless, good to know that unless its a large array, it won't matter too much. Thanks for the assistance everyone!

Comment: @AlexGravely I don't believe that the array size has any impact on the overhead - it's two extra instructions regardless (it was the looping in your benchmark that made the difference, so the number of arrays is what you should consider).  For which you use, I would go with personal preference or team standards, but one benefit to the first way is that if you want to insert a value in the middle, you don't have to mess with the other indexes.  You can always split the values over multiple lines in whatever way looks the most pleasing.